# How do I download the terminal application for Ubuntu 12.04 in Lubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, gnome-terminal

I recently installed Lubuntu. The terminal look and feel are not as good as compared to L&F for terminal that I used use in Ubuntu 12.04.

I would like to know from where and how can I download the same terminal that I was using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The terminal that you get along with the LXDE package is `lxterminal`. To install the terminal application that generally comes along GNOME is `gnome-terminal`.

Installation:

Type in

`sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`

in the `lxterminal`.

another good looking terminal that allows you to dropdown on pressing F12, looks fancy and comes handy is the guake terminal. Try it by typing :

`sudo apt-get install guake`

in the `lxterminal`.

And hope those are the last commands that you use in `lxterminal`

Answer (score 6):

You just have to install it from the repositories. It will pull in some dependencies, but they won't affect your system.

Click here to install: [gnome-terminal [image: Install gnome-terminal]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-terminal)

Or run `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`